# initializing multiple ImageButton in a fragment and add a SetOnClickListener in all of them

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, onclicklistener, buttonclick

[heres what happen when i used the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkdi8.png)     public class MenFragment extends Fragment {

```
ImageButton imageButtonCald;
ImageButton imageButtonCk;
ImageButton imageButtonCr;
ImageButton imageButtonTLt;
ImageButton imageButtonSttic;
ImageButton imageButtonSh;
View rootView;


public MenFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_men, container, false);
    imageButtonCald = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cald);
    imageButtonCk = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ck);
    imageButtonCr = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cr);
    imageButtonTLt = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tlt);
    imageButtonSttic = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sttc);
    imageButtonSch = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sch);


    /*here i add a setOnClickListener method the my first button , how to add to the one */
    imageButtonCald.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CaldActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

i already add a 'setOnClickListener' to the first button , how can i add a 'setOnClickListener' method on the other one.

Comment: Refer this : https://uwudamith.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/how-to-use-onclicklistener-in-android

Comment: Sure Thank you ,in this example it show a Toast, how Do i call Another Activity with my buttons

Comment: write `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),YourActivity.class));` for starting a new activity

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement onClicklistener in you Fragment.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
        false);

 Button button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.try_button1);     
 Button button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.try_button2);    
 Button button3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.try_button3);     
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
 button3.setOnClickListener(this);

 return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int viedId = v.getId();
 switch(viedId ){
  case R.id.try_button1:
  //your implementation here
  break;
  case R.id.try_button2:
  //your implementation here
  break;
  case R.id.try_button3:
  //your implementation here
  break;

 }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! how Do i call Another Activity ?

Comment: you can use Intent to call another activity `startActivtiy(new Intent(getActivty(),NextActivity.class);`